# need help echo in index.php from process.php

Tags: php

After my form has been submitted and my message has been sent I want to go back to the index which this does, but I also want to display echo 'Message has been sent' in the index.php in a div instead of my process.php, how would I go about doing this. Sort of new to php if you need any more of my code I will provide or link to site. Thanks.

This is what i tried so far.
in my process.php file

```
if(!$mail->send()) {
    $output = 1;
    // $output = 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    $output = 2;
    header('Location:index.php');
}
```

in my index.php file

```
<?php 
    if ($output == 2) { 
        echo "<b>Message has been sent</b>";
    } elseif ($output == 1) { 
        echo "<b>Message could not be sent, please try again</b>";
    } else {}
?>
```

Comment: index.php can't get the value of $output.you can use session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable $output isn't set in your index.php file.

As an easy way to start you can try it like

```
 header('Location:index.php?output='.$output);
```

and fetch output in your index.php with

```
$output = $_GET['output'];
```

at the beginning of your file, that way you will be able to make your if statements work.

Also be advised that you will never be redirected if $output = 1 in your process.php, as the header is only in the else statement. Simply place the header after your else statements closing bracket.

```
if(!$mail->send()) {
    $output = 1;

} else {
    $output = 2;

}
header('Location:index.php?output='.$output);
die();
```

**index.php:**

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['output'])) {
$output = $_GET['output'];
if ($output == 2) { 
    echo "<b>Message has been sent</b>";
} elseif ($output == 1) { 
    echo "<b>Message could not be sent, please try again</b>";
} 
}
```

Please be advised that you shouldn't use unsanitized request data (user input and what so ever) in a production environment, as this is a security risk.

Comment: Thank you so much this solved my problem and taught me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work, the value won't get passed to the index this way:

```
} else {
    $output = 2;
    header('Location:index.php');
}
```

Your options (short of redesigning the way it works) are POST or GET;

```
} else {
    $output = 2;
    header('Location:index.php?sent=1');
}
```

Then in your index.php:

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_GET['sent']) &&  $_GET['sent'] == 1) { 
        echo "<b>Message has been sent</b>";
    } 
?>
```